# Having a hard time my code

Tags: c++

I am taking a C++ class and I have to build a payroll system.  I am having a hard time trying to figure out what is wrong with my code.  I can get the employees hours to produce but I have an new issue with my code now. I thought it was correct, but guess not. Now the new problem is that I can get the employees hours to produce but when I do my code wants to multiple my overtime hours times 3 and produce an output of the person who has the overtime hours twice.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>    
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

//
//CLASS DECLARATION SECTION
//

class EmployeeClass {
public:
void ImplementCalculations(string EmployeeName, int hours, float wage);
void DisplayEmployInformation(void);
void Addsomethingup (EmployeeClass Emp1, EmployeeClass Emp2, EmployeeClass Emp3);
string EmployeeName;
int hours ;
float wage ;
float basepay ;
int overtime_hours ;
float overtime_pay ;
float overtime_extra ;
float iTotal_salaries ;
float iIndividualSalary ;
int iTotal_hours ;
int iTotal_OvertimeHours ;
};

int main()
{   system("cls");

cout << "\nWelcome to Data Max Inc. Employee Pay Center\n\n" ;


EmployeeClass Emp1;
EmployeeClass Emp2;
EmployeeClass Emp3;

cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl;

cout << "\n\nEnter the first employee's first name = ";
cin >> Emp1.EmployeeName;

cout << "\n\nEnter the hours worked = ";
cin >> Emp1.hours;

cout << "\n\nEnter employee's hourly wage = ";
cin >> Emp1.wage;

cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl;

cout << "\n\nEnter the second employee's first name = ";
cin >> Emp2.EmployeeName;

cout << "\n\nEnter the hours worked = ";
cin >> Emp2.hours;

cout << "\n\nEnter employee's hourly wage = ";
cin >> Emp2.wage;

cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl;

cout << "\n\nEnter the third employee's first name = ";
cin >> Emp3.EmployeeName;

cout << "\n\nEnter the hours worked = ";
cin >> Emp3.hours;

cout << "\n\nEnter employee's hourly wage = ";
cin >> Emp3.wage;

cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl;
cout << endl;

Emp1.ImplementCalculations(Emp1.EmployeeName, Emp1.hours, Emp1.wage);
Emp2.ImplementCalculations(Emp2.EmployeeName, Emp2.hours, Emp2.wage);
Emp3.ImplementCalculations(Emp3.EmployeeName, Emp3.hours, Emp3.wage);



cin.get();
    return 0;    

} //End of Main Function


void EmployeeClass::ImplementCalculations (string employeeFirstName, int hours, float wage){
//Initialize overtime variables
overtime_hours=0;
overtime_pay=0;
overtime_extra=0;

if (hours > 40)
{      


basepay = 40 * wage;
overtime_hours = hours - 40;
overtime_pay = wage * 1.5;
overtime_extra = overtime_hours * overtime_pay;
iIndividualSalary = overtime_extra + basepay;


DisplayEmployInformation();

}   // if (hours > 40)
else
{  
basepay = hours * wage;
iIndividualSalary = basepay;


} // End of the else

DisplayEmployInformation();


} //End of Primary Function

void EmployeeClass::DisplayEmployInformation () {
// This function displays all the employee output information.



cout << "\n\n";
cout << "Employee First Name ............. = " << EmployeeName << endl;
cout << "Base Pay ........................ = " << basepay << endl;
cout << "Hours in Overtime ............... = " << overtime_hours << endl;
cout << "Overtime Pay Amout............... = " << overtime_extra << endl;
cout << "Total Pay ....................... = " << iIndividualSalary << endl;




} // END OF Display Employee Information

void EmployeeClass::Addsomethingup (EmployeeClass Emp1, EmployeeClass Emp2,        EmployeeClass Emp3){

iTotal_salaries = 0;
iTotal_hours = 0;
iTotal_OvertimeHours = 0;


iTotal_hours = Emp1.hours + Emp2.hours + Emp3.hours;
iTotal_salaries = iIndividualSalary + iIndividualSalary + iIndividualSalary;
iTotal_OvertimeHours = overtime_hours + overtime_hours + overtime_hours;



cout << "\n\n";
cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl;
cout << "%%%% EMPLOYEE SUMMARY DATA%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl;
cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl;
cout << "%%%% Total Employee Salaries ..... = " << iTotal_salaries << endl;
cout << "%%%% Total Employee Hours ........ = " << iTotal_hours << endl;
cout << "%%%% Total Overtime Hours......... = " << iTotal_OvertimeHours << endl;
cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl;
cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl;

} // End of function
```

Comment: A far better practice is to have your class method return a `string` and print that from main.

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly is happening? Do you get an error trace or unexpected output? Please be specific.

Comment: I am not getting any errors at all.  As far as my output I am getting nothing in regards to my Employee Data Summary.  I am able to produce an output of the each of the 3 employee hours, salary, and overtime hours, but am unable to produce the total hours, total salary, and total overtime hours for all 3 of the employees combined.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't calling `Addsomethingup` anywhere. You probably also want this to be a `static` method. If you haven't learned what those are yet, don't worry.

At the end of your `main` function, but before `cin.get()`, try adding:

```
Emp1.Addsomethingup(Emp1, Emp2, Emp3);
```

Comment: Thank You, Thank You, and again Thank you.  That is what I needed.  You guys are a wonderful help